# ICMP Golang with raw socket, control message has nil value

Tags: go, ping, icmp, ttl

I'm playing around with the ICMP raw socket of Golang. I'd like to read the TTL which is part the control message returned by `ReadFrom(buffer)`.

Weirdly this value is always `nil`, is there something I'm missing.

Please find below my playground code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {

    c, _ := icmp.ListenPacket("ip4:icmp", "")

    rb := make([]byte, 1500)
    for true {

        n, cm, peer, _ := c.IPv4PacketConn().ReadFrom(rb)
        rm, _ := icmp.ParseMessage(ipv4.ICMPTypeEchoReply.Protocol(), rb[:n])

        switch rm.Type {
        case ipv4.ICMPTypeEchoReply:
            {
                fmt.Printf("received answer from %s\n", peer)
                if cm != nil {
                    println(cm.TTL)
                } else {
                    println("empty control message")
                }

            }
        default:

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out what was missing.

Before reading, it is required to set IP socket options.

In my case, I was interested in TTL, so:

```
        _ = c.IPv4PacketConn().SetControlMessage(ipv4.FlagTTL, true)
```